# Ignore special characters in \newcommand argument to generate section labels?

Tags: macros, sectioning, cross-referencing, characters

I am editing a rather large document and have replaced `\section`, `\subsection` etc with `\newcommand` macros that include `\section` etc but also spacing and other commands.  I am trying to get it to automatically label the sections for cross referencing, eg `\label{sec:#1}`.  However, some of the pre-existing section titles have special characters and commands. It is not feasible to go back through and label them manually.  Is there any way to have tell my macro to ignore special characters and generate a label verbatim from what is typed?

Comment: My feeling is that this would be almost useless: if you have `\label{sec:Café}` and remove `é`, then you'll need to do `\ref{sec:Caf}` unless you also redefine `\ref`. Not worthy a try, I'm afraid.

Comment: Labels should be defined in most cases to have a short name, easy to remember. It's not useful to put the whole section name into a label name, regardless whether special characters are used or not -- those abel names would be difficult to remember

Comment: why have a command that includes `\section` together width spacing? that sounds very wrong, the whole idea is that you just have `\section` and that is then customised to make the spacing that you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by the comments (wrong to try this...).